# Device message rate limit for Android GCM?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

What is the device message rate limit in Android GCM? Why does the limit exist?

Comment: why you are asking question if you know the answer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. We receive this question regularly.

Answer (score 3):

The Device message rate limit is added to manage misbehaving apps that send unreasonable amounts of messages to clients, which causes problems to end users, e.g. by draining the device battery.

This limit is set high and should not affect well behaving apps. But as a best practice, when the app server attempts to send a message to a device, it should be prepared to handle the device message rate limit error code. 
There are [resources available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790810/rate-limit-exceeded-error-when-using-google-cloud-messaging-api/26790811#26790811) that explain how to handle this error message, including an [explanation on how to work well with rate limits](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/ExponentialBackoff).